# Word or phrase for "Normal for that person"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a single word, or phrase, meaning that this is the state that this person is normally in.

In context I have a sentence: "Now, {As was normal for her}, she was smiling with sincerity.". An alternative to {as was normal for her} would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious word that comes to mind is ***typical***:

> Having the distinctive qualities of a particular type of person or thing; characteristic of a particular person or thing ([*ODO*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/typical))

In your example, the most normal way to phrase this would be to use *typical* as an adjective modifying the thing that is typical of someone, rather than as an adverb or sentential adverb to comment on the way in which the person is doing it. In other words:

> Now she was smiling with *her typical sincerity*.

Some common synonyms for this usage would be [*usual*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/usual) and [*characteristic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/characteristic).

If you are specifically looking for a phrase that you can insert into your sentence at that exact place, the most idiomatic phrasing I can think of is [***as was her wont***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wont).

Answer (score 3):

Gertrude, ***as was her wont*** was smiling with sincerity.

***wont*** n. FORMAL or HUMOROUS one's customary behaviour: *Constance, as was her wont, had paid little attention*. ORIGIN Old English *gewunod*, past participle of *wunian*, 'dwell, be accustomed', of Germanic origin.  (Oxford Dictionaries - not OED).

Comment: This duplicates Janus' answer.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Apologies for doing that. If you want I will delete, but thought it was worth leaving for the etymology.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest: "Now she was smiling with her **habitual** sincerity".

The use of "habitual" perhaps indicates that the subject's smile was typical of her personally, rather than typical of anyone/anything else.

Answer (score 1):

"Now, characteristically, she was smiling with sincerity." (She's a very nice person - maybe *too* nice)

"Now, as per her idiom, she was smiling with sincerity." (Her heart is black as coal - this is just another performance.)

Comment: I spent a good five minutes trying to think of another word commonly used as a synonym for _typical_ and _usual_, having in the end to accept that it just wouldn’t come to me. _Characteristic_ was the elusive word, thank you! I hope you don’t mind that I add the adjective form to my answer.

Comment: I've never seen anyone use "as per her idiom"